# Stress- energy tensor in AdS

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, ads-cft, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I´m trying to reproduce some of the equations from the paper
-- A Stress Tensor For Anti-de Sitter Gravity, by Balasubramanian and Kraus,
https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9902121 -- and I keep getting one of them wrong.

It is the equation for $T_{xx}$ in Eq. (19) from the cited paper, which gives the $xx$ component of the stress-energy tensor for 3-dimensional Anti-de Siter spacetime. The $AdS_{3}$ metric in Poincaré coordinates $\{t,r,x\}$ is

$$ 
ds^2 = \frac{l^2}{r^2} dr^2 + \frac{r^2}{l^2} \left(-dt^2 + dx^2\right) .
$$

According to Eq. (9) from the cited paper, the stress-energy tensor for $AdS_{3}$ should be defined as a functional of the boundary metric, $\gamma_{\mu\nu}$, and be given by

\begin{equation}
 8 \pi G T^{\mu\nu} = \Theta^{\mu\nu} - \Theta \gamma^{\mu\nu} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \frac{\delta S_{ct}}{\delta \gamma_{\mu\nu}} 
\end{equation}

where  $\Theta_{\mu \nu} = - \frac{1}{2} \left( \nabla_{\mu} \hat{n}_{\nu} + \nabla_{\nu}\hat{n}_{\mu} \right)$ is the extrinsic curvature of the boundary with unit normal $\hat{n}^{\mu} = \frac{r}{l}\delta^{\mu,r}$, $\Theta$  its trace, and $S_{ct}$ the counterterm necessary to cancel the divergences.

Computing $\Theta_{xx}$ and $\Theta$ I obtain

$$ \Theta_{xx} = \frac{-r^2}{l^3} \quad, \quad  \Theta = \frac{-2}{l} $$
which after substitution in the Eq. for $T_{xx}$
gives

$$ 
8 \pi G T_{xx} =  \frac{r^2}{l^3} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \frac{\delta S_{ct}}{\delta \gamma^{xx}}
$$
which is obviously different from the paper, which is given by

$$ 
8 \pi G T_{xx} =  \frac{r^2}{l} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \frac{\delta S_{ct}}{\delta \gamma^{xx}}
$$

Can anyone give me a hint of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like a typo in the paper. Any reason you believe that the paper has to be correct (for instance, do they use this result in a future calculation)? PS - Clearly given the symmetry between the $t$ and $x$ coordinates, his $T_{xx}$ and $T_{tt}$ must have the same scaling (w.r.t. $\ell$) which makes me believe that the paper has a typo.